# Need Help In EXCEL VBA match and copy

Tags: vba, excel

I am working in one of the Excel sheet and i am new in VBA. I have a situation where i have 2 different sheets ("OriginalData1") and ("VBAFilter"). I have one cell (F3) in ("VBAFilter") sheet and it has a company name, which appear in "OriginalData1" multiple times. I want to find the same company name in ("OriginalData1") sheet. If it appears 4 times in "OriginalData1" I need to transfer in "VBAFilter" same 4 times and if it is a match then copy the entire row and paste it in sheet("VBAFilter") in cell range (F3:O2000").

Here's the code i have:

```
Sub datafind()

Dim CompanyName As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Worksheets("VBAFilter").Range("F9:O1000").ClearContents
CompanyName = Sheets("VBAFilter").Range("F3").Value
finalrow = Sheets("OriginalData1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To finalrow

 If Worksheets("OriginalData1").Cells(i, 2) = CompanyName Then
    Worksheets("OriginalData1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).Copy
    Worksheets("VBAFilter").Select
    Range("F1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub datafind()

Dim CompanyName As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

j= 9

Worksheets("VBAFilter").Range("F9:O1000").ClearContents
CompanyName = Sheets("VBAFilter").Range("F3").Value
finalrow = Sheets("OriginalData1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To finalrow

    If Worksheets("OriginalData1").Cells(i, 2) = CompanyName Then
        Worksheets("OriginalData1").Cells(i, 2).Resize(1,1000).Copy
        Worksheets("OriginalData1").Cells(j, "F").Resize(1,1000).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any clue that if i want these all three "VBAFilter" Values "F3","D3" and "C3" will match to the "OriginalData1" Cells"B2","C2","I3". 
THANKS AGAIN Siphor

Comment: And also i need to calculate the total in cell "F1001" or wherever my data will end.

Comment: Any reason why you dont use a pivot table?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I was doing the project and i was asked to use VBA